# 10415 Patch error in magento1

Tags: magento-1.9, patches

I install fresh `magento 1.9.3.2` .

I tried to install **Patch 10415** by creating following file on root named patch.php

```
<?php
print("<PRE>");
passthru("/bin/bash PATCH_SUPEE-10415_CE_1.9.3.2_v1-2017-11-28-06-38-23.sh");
print("</PRE>");
echo "Done";
```

?>

I also downloaded **PATCH_SUPEE-10415_CE_1.9.3.2_v1-2017-11-28-06-38-23.sh** file and placed on root.

The following error is displayed

> Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
>       ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.
>
> ```
> checking file app/Mage.php
> checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Report/Review/Detail.php
> checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Report/Tag/Product/Detail.php
> checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Review/Add.php
> checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Review/Edit/Form.php
> checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php
> Hunk #1 FAILED at 186.
> 1 out of 1 hunk FAILED
> checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/LayoutUpdate/Validator.php
> Hunk #1 FAILED at 142.
> 1 out of 1 hunk FAILED
> checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/System/Config/Backend/Filename.php
> checking file app/code/core/Mage/Api/Helper/Data.php
> checking file app/code/core/Mage/Api/Model/Server/Adapter/Soap.php
> checking file app/code/core/Mage/Api/Model/Wsdl/Config.php
> checking file app/code/core/Mage/Api/Model/Wsdl/Config/Base.php
> checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/String.php
> checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/File/Validator/Image.php
> Hunk #1 FAILED at 91.
> 1 out of 1 hunk FAILED
> checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/config.xml
> Hunk #1 FAILED at 467.
> 1 out of 1 hunk FAILED
> checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/system.xml
> Hunk #1 succeeded at 673 (offset -1 lines).
> Hunk #2 succeeded at 683 (offset -1 lines).
> checking file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Customer.php
> checking file app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/Backend/Serialized.php
> checking file app/code/core/Mage/Log/Helper/Data.php
> checking file app/code/core/Mage/Rule/Model/Abstract.php
> checking file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Block/Adminhtml/Billing/Agreement/Grid.php
> checking file app/code/core/Zend/Form/Decorator/Form.php
> checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/backup/dialogs.phtml
> Hunk #1 FAILED at 158.
> 1 out of 1 hunk FAILED
> checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/billing/agreement/view/tab/info.phtml
> checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/xmlconnect/edit/tab/content.phtml
> checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/xmlconnect/edit/tab/design/image_edit.phtml
> checking file app/locale/en_US/Mage_Adminhtml.csv
> checking file app/locale/en_US/Mage_Customer.csv
> checking file js/mage/adminhtml/backup.js
> checking file lib/Varien/Filter/FormElementName.php
> Done
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The magento ver 1.9.3.2  includes this patches

> SUPEE-5344, SUPEE-5994, SUPEE-6237, SUPEE-6285, SUPEE-6482,
>   SUPEE-6788, SUPEE-7616, SUPEE-7405, SUPEE-7405 v1.1, SUPEE-8788,
>   SUPEE-9652

You are trying to install a patch with number 10415 , and it is displaying errors because you are skipping

> SUPEE-10266
>
> SUPEE-10336
>
> SUPEE-9767 v2

By the logic its supposed you installed the patches i mentioned , but you didnt , thats why you are getting errors. 
Not sure why you are trying to install a 1.9.3.2 while you can install a magento version that include that patch you asking . 
As i know you cant easily skip 3 patches.

Answer (score 0):

Roll back the changes you made, if any. For patching, use this utility: https://github.com/magesec/magesecuritypatcher. Upload to your server's Magento directory then give it chmod u+x then run it. Patches files up to current spec from the Magento repo. Very handy.

I have patched sites missing five plus patches flawlessly with this utility.